# Uber API rider rating

Tags: uber-api

Can I retrive rider rating from Uber API ?

There is only '/v1.2/me' endpoint, but it's returning only:

```
{
  "picture": "https://d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net/f3be498cb0bbf570aa3d.jpeg",
  "first_name": "Uber",
  "last_name": "Developer",
  "uuid": "f4a416e3-6016-4623-8ec9-d5ee105a6e27",
  "rider_id": "8OlTlUG1TyeAQf1JiBZZdkKxuSSOUwu2IkO0Hf9d2HV52Pm25A0NvsbmbnZr85tLVi-s8CckpBK8Eq0Nke4X-no3AcSHfeVh6J5O6LiQt5LsBZDSi4qyVUdSLeYDnTtirw==",
  "email": "uberdevelopers@gmail.com",
  "mobile_verified": true,
  "promo_code": "uberd340ue"
}
```

...without rider rating

Answer (score 0):

Those appear to be the expected returned fields according to the documentation. Rider rating is not one of the returned fields from that profile endpoint:

https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/me-get